# a simple calculator command line utility (division)

Tags: python

I created a calculator in python and everything works besides dividing a number by zero.
I want the program to return "error: cannot divide by Zero" if the user inputs 10 0

Instead, I get the this long error message

```
(env) Sarahs-Air:bin sarahbreslin$ python calc3.py 
divide 10 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "calc3.py", line 54, in <module>
calculator()

  File "/Users/sarahbreslin/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarahbreslin/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  
 File "/Users/sarahbreslin/env/lib/python3.8/site- 

packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
     return 
 _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/sarahbreslin/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/sarahbreslin/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
 packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)

File "calc3.py", line 40, in divide

print("division =", num1/num2) 

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Here is the code I've written

```
#division command
@calculator.command()
@click.option('--i', is_flag = True , help="forcing 
integer division")
@click.argument('num1', type=int)
@click.argument('num2', type=int)
def divide(i,num1,num2):
    '''
    Divide two integers (num1/num2).
    To force integer division, use --i option.
    '''
    if(i):
        print("division =", num1//num2)
    else:
        print("division =", num1/num2)
```

Comment: You can check if `num2 == 0` and in that case, don't do the division. Print an error message or something.

Answer (score 0):

Either do this to allow the program to continue running

```
#division command
@calculator.command()
@click.option('--i', is_flag = True , help="forcing 
integer division")
@click.argument('num1', type=int)
@click.argument('num2', type=int)
def divide(i,num1,num2):
    '''
    Divide two integers (num1/num2).
    To force integer division, use --i option.
    '''

    if num2 == 0:
        print('error: cannot divide by Zero')
    else:

        if(i):
            print("division =", num1//num2)
        else:
            print("division =", num1/num2)
```

Or this to raise an error

```
#division command
@calculator.command()
@click.option('--i', is_flag = True , help="forcing 
integer division")
@click.argument('num1', type=int)
@click.argument('num2', type=int)
def divide(i,num1,num2):
    '''
    Divide two integers (num1/num2).
    To force integer division, use --i option.
    '''

    if num2 == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('Cannot divide by zero')
    else:

        if(i):
            print("division =", num1//num2)
        else:
            print("division =", num1/num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error to replace it with a shorter one:

```py
#division command
@calculator.command()
@click.option('--i', is_flag = True , help="forcing 
integer division")
@click.argument('num1', type=int)
@click.argument('num2', type=int)
def divide(i, num1, num2):
    '''
    Divide two integers (num1/num2).
    To force integer division, use --i option.
    '''
    try:
        if(i):
            print("division =", num1 // num2)
        else:
            print("division =", num1 / num2)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("error: cannot divide by Zero")
```

The adventage is that it is still a "python error".